# Connect CSS with Bottle

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I have this code to connect the CSS files with HTML:

```
from bottle import static_file

@route("/static/<filename>")
def static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root="static")
```

Then I have this code:

```
@route("/edit/<name>")
def edit(name):
    return template("edit")
```

The problem is that my template edit.html can't connect to the CSS file which is in the static folder. But it works when I have a code like this:

```
@route("/edit/")
def edit(name):
    return template("edit")
```

...without the name tag

Comment: I'm confused. The second version of `edit` should not work at all; it should fail because Bottle will try to call your `edit` function with zero parameters, while it's expecting one (`TypeError`).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the CSS reference in the file "edit.html" looks something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
```

I personally solve this problem by adding a slash at the beginning of the CSS file path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">
```

In this way, the connection refers to the "static" folder within the root directory of the site.